# How to remove the specific text node from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, dom

I'm trying to remove the text node "**one**".

$targetDiv is jQuery object

```
$targetDiv[0].outerHTML
<div><div>one<font face="Impact" size="4">www</font></div></div>

$targetDiv[0].innerHTML
<div>one<font face="Impact" size="4">www</font></div>
```

I can remove the other text node "**www**" like below:

```
$targetDiv.find("font").each(function ()
{
   if (this.firstChild.nodeType === 3)
   {
       this.firstChild.data = "";
   }
});
```

But having tough time removing the "one" part.

```
$targetDiv[0].firstChild
<div>

$targetDiv[0].firstChild.data
undefined

$targetDiv[0].firstChild.innerText
undefined

$targetDiv[0].firstChild.innerHTML
"one<font face="Impact" size="4">www</font>"

$targetDiv[0].firstChild.innerText
undefined

$targetDiv[0].firstChild.textContent
"onewww"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very clear what context this is  in, or what `$targetDiv` is, but based on the results you're getting we can assume you are using Firefox, and that `$targetDiv` is the first div, and that this should work

```
$($targetDiv.find("div").get(0).firstChild).remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VGaR2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native `.removeChild` method to remove the first text node:

```
var div=targetDiv[0].firstChild;
div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
```

This method is invoked from the parent of the node that you wish to remove, and receives the node to remove as its argument.

---

Modern browsers let you simply call `.remove()` on the node itself.

```
target[0].firstChild.firstChild.remove();
```

---

Your `.each()` loop was close. In that particular case, since the `one` text node is the only sibling that is a text node, you'd just iterate the children under target since there's only one.

```
$targetDiv.children("div").each(function ()
{
   if (this.firstChild.nodeType === 3)
   {
       this.firstChild.data = "";
   }
});
```

Though targeting it directly instead of a loop makes more sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$($targetDiv.children('div').contents()[0]).remove();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VGaR2/1/)